# SO_REUSEPORT on linux

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I want to know if SO_REUSEPORT option is enabled in LINUX 2.6 or not ??

If I try to use it and compile my code I get following error

```
01.c:72: error: `SO_REUSEPORT' undeclared (first use in this function)
01.c:72: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
01.c:72: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Using the above option I guess I can bind two different sockets to same IPADRESS and PORT NUMBER

Answer (score 8):

this options was done in kernel 3.9, see this git commit

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c617f398edd4db2b8567a28e899a88f8f574798d

Answer (score 6):

From `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h`:

```
/* For setsockopt(2) */
#define SOL_SOCKET      1

#define SO_DEBUG        1
#define SO_REUSEADDR    2
#define SO_TYPE         3
#define SO_ERROR        4
#define SO_DONTROUTE    5
#define SO_BROADCAST    6
#define SO_SNDBUF       7
#define SO_RCVBUF       8
#define SO_SNDBUFFORCE  32
#define SO_RCVBUFFORCE  33
#define SO_KEEPALIVE    9
#define SO_OOBINLINE    10
#define SO_NO_CHECK     11
#define SO_PRIORITY     12
#define SO_LINGER       13
#define SO_BSDCOMPAT    14
/* To add :#define SO_REUSEPORT 15 */
```

Hmmm. Looks like it's undefined or on the last stages of being depreciated.

Here's what [a post on KernelTrap](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-netdev/2008/8/7/2851904) says:

> On Linux, SO_REUSEADDR provide most of what SO_REUSEPORT provides on BSD.
>
> In any case, there is absolutely no point in creating multiple TCP listeners.
>      Multiple threads can accept() on the same listener - at the same time.
>      --
>      Rémi Denis-Courmont
>      http://www.remlab.net/

Comment: I am not sure what does "SO_REUSEPORT" does in BSd ... but I have loosely heard that I can even bind two different sockets with same Source IPADRESS and Source Port ..

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#ifdefined (SO_REUSEPORT)
... set this option
#endif
```

Some platforms (OS/X for one) need this to be set if you're e.g. binding multiple UDP listeners to one port.

Answer (score 4):

SO_REUSEPORT was backported to the RHEL6.5 kernel 2.6.32.

Answer (score 3):

It was added during the 3.9 cycle in a series of patches by Tom Herbert, as you can see [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/), in order to better support multithreaded web servers.

The patch itself can be found [here](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/50430/) if you want to integrate SO_REUSEPORT into an older kernel version.

And yes, you can use SO_REUSEPORT to bind a socket to the same address and port as another connection, as long as the initial connection also uses SO_REUSEPORT (and any other connections sharing the source address and port).  This is done to prevent port hijacking by rogue applications.